# Nested HTML Elements & Height

Tags: css

I have a very basic question regarding CSS. Say i set the height of my BODY tag to 100%...and then within the body tag I have a DIV and that DIV can have many other nested DIV. now do I have to specify HEIGHT for every single DIV? why cant they inherit from parent by Default.

For Example..

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Now my HTML is...

```
<body>
<div id="container">
   <div id="header">
     <div class="header_inner"></div>
     <div class="header_inner"></div>
   </div>
</div>
</body>
```

So, Do i have to specify the height for "container" to 100% as well? why cant it inherit from parent(Body) automatically? now say if I do specify the height on "container" to be 100%, and I want my header to be "100%" as well, Then I have to do the same thing again on "header"?

I guess the question is...do all the HTML elements need to have HEIGHT "Specified", cant they just auto inherit from parent?

I tried to use

```
* {
  height: inherit
}
```

but it am not sure whether this is the RIGHT way of doing it or not?

Comment: Which tags does `inherit` break on? I think it should work on all `display: block` elements. In general, `height` is not inherited and a `div` is as high as it needs to be to contain its content or reach the boundaries set by the parent element (i.e. `100%`).

Comment: so if a parent has a height of 700px and then DIV inside it will also inherit 700px? or I have to hardcode it in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div will not inherit the height of the parent by default. If you want to inherit the height, you have to specify that in the CSS for the div.

In general, you have to specify the height of a block element or it will only be as high as it needs to be to contain its content.

See this example:

```css
.outer {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 100px;
}

.inner-inherit {
  background-color: green;
  height: inherit;
}

.inner-no-inherit {
  background-color: yellow;
}

p {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-inherit">
    <p>I inherit my height from parent</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="outer">
  <div class="inner-no-inherit">
    <p>I am only as high as the text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```